# Spark akka throws a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc

Tags: java, apache-spark, akka, spark-streaming

I have built spark using scala 2.11. I ran the following steps :

```
./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package
```

After building spark successfully, I tried to intialize spark via akka model .
So, my Main class looks like :

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("ClusterSystem");
Inbox inbox = Inbox.create(system);
ActorRef sparkActorRef = system.actorOf(SparkActor.props(mapOfArguments), "sparkActor");
inbox.send(sparkActorRef, "start");
```

The spark actor looks like:

```
      public class SparkActor extends UntypedActor{

            private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SparkActor.class);

            final Map<String,Object> configurations;
            final SparkConf sparkConf;
            private int sparkBatchDuration;

              public static Props props(final Map<String,Object> configurations) {
                    return Props.create(new Creator<SparkActor>() {
                      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                      @Override
                      public SparkActor create() throws Exception {
                        return new SparkActor(configurations);
                      }
                    });
                  }



              public SparkActor(Map<String,Object> configurations) {
                this.configurations = configurations;
                this.sparkConf =initializeSparkConf(configurations);
ActorRef mediator = DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
        mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("data", getSelf()), getSelf());
              }

            private SparkConf initializeSparkConf(Map<String, Object> mapOfArgs) {
                SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
                Configuration sparkConf = (Configuration) mapOfArgs.get(StreamingConstants.MAP_SPARK_CONFIGURATION);
                Iterator it = sparkConf.getKeys();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    String propertyKey = (String)it.next();
                    String propertyValue = sparkConf.getString(propertyKey);
                    conf.set(propertyKey.trim(), propertyValue.trim());
                }
                conf.setMaster(sparkConf.getString(StreamingConstants.SET_MASTER));
                return conf;
            }



            @Override
            public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {
                if((arg0 instanceof String) & (arg0.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("start"))){
                    logger.info("Going to start");
                    sparkConf.setAppName(StreamingConstants.APP_NAME);
                    logger.debug("App name set to {}. Beginning spark execution",StreamingConstants.APP_NAME);
                    Configuration kafkaConfiguration  = (Configuration) configurations.get(StreamingConstants.MAP_KAFKA_CONFIGURATION);
                    sparkBatchDuration = Integer.parseInt((String)configurations.get(StreamingConstants.MAP_SPARK_DURATION));

                    //Initializing Kafka configurations.
                    String[] eplTopicsAndThreads = kafkaConfiguration.getString(StreamingConstants.EPL_QUEUE).split(",");
                    Map<String,Integer> mapofeplTopicsAndThreads = new TreeMap<>();
                    for (String item : eplTopicsAndThreads){
                        String topic = item.split(StreamingConstants.EPL_QUEUE_SEPARATOR)[0];
                        Integer numberOfThreads= Integer.parseInt(item.split(StreamingConstants.EPL_QUEUE_SEPARATOR)[1]);
                        mapofeplTopicsAndThreads.put(topic, numberOfThreads);
                    }

                    //Creating a receiver stream in spark 
                    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String,String> receiverStream = null;
                    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(sparkBatchDuration));
                    receiverStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 
                            kafkaConfiguration.getString(StreamingConstants.ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_PROPERTY), 
                            kafkaConfiguration.getString(StreamingConstants.KAFKA_GROUP_NAME),
                            mapofeplTopicsAndThreads);
                    JavaDStream<String> javaRdd = receiverStream.map(new SparkTaskTupleHelper());
                    javaRdd.foreachRDD(new Function<JavaRDD<String>, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> jsonData) throws Exception {
    //Code to process some data from kafka
                        }
                    });

                    ssc.start();
                    ssc.awaitTermination();
                }

            }
```

I start my spark application as

./spark-submit --class com.sample.Main --master local[8] ../executables/spark-akka.jar

I get the following exception on startup

```
Uncaught error from thread [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[ClusterSystem]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at akka.cluster.pubsub.protobuf.DistributedPubSubMessageSerializer.<init>(DistributedPubSubMessageSerializer.scala:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:200)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.serializerOf(Serialization.scala:165)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$3.apply(Serialization.scala:174)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$3.apply(Serialization.scala:174)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:722)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:721)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.<init>(Serialization.scala:174)
    at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:15)
    at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.createExtension(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:713)
    at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
    at akka.serialization.SerializationExtension$.apply(SerializationExtension.scala:12)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:175)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:620)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:617)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:617)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:634)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1913)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:450)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.createNewSparkContext(StreamingContext.scala:864)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.<init>(StreamingContext.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.<init>(JavaStreamingContext.scala:134)
    at com.sample.SparkActor.onReceive(SparkActor.java:106)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
```

A list of options that I have already tried..
1) rebuilt spark with akka version 2.4.4 and got a NoSuchMethodError for toRootLowerCase
2) Tried to reuse the inbuilt spark of 2.3.11 and still got the same exception at CLusterSettings.scala

I have looked at similar errors on stackoverflow and found that it was due to a scala version mismatch. But having built everything with 2.11 and using akka 2.4.4 I thought that all jars will be on the same scala version.

Am i missing any particular step?

My pom file for your reference.

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.6</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>2.0-rc1</log4j.version>
        <commons.cli.version>1.2</commons.cli.version>
        <kafka.version>0.8.2.2</kafka.version>
        <akka.version>2.4.4</akka.version>
        <akka.version.old>2.4.4</akka.version.old>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-cluster_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-kernel_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-cluster-tools_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${akka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-remote_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

If I remove the cluster jars and the distributedpubsub code and use plain remoting i.e akka.tcp then no errors are shown. It works fine in that scenario. I wish to know why the distributedpubsub throws this error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the scala version specific artificats. I had to use 2.10 instead of 2.11